# Next.js header does not work on first load, only after refresh

Tags: next.js

I need to use SharedArrayBuffer for a specific page, so I put this in next.config.js:

```
async headers() {
return [
  {
    source: '/upload',
    headers: [
      {
        key: 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy',
        value: 'require-corp',
      },
      {
        key: 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy',
        value: 'same-origin',
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

},

The problem is, this only works when I go to the page and I do a refresh.

Comment: It seems that the app headers are set on first page load. If you want to update app headers for a route a reload is needed, sadly.